# Coloring text inside jquery function while focused in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to color the text **Enter Valid Email** in **Red** how can i achieve this Please Help

email_validation.js

```
$('#email').focusin(function()
{
    $('#email_feed').text('Enter Valid Email...');
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Add another line $('#email_feed').css('color','red'); in focusin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** property

```
$('#email_feed').text('Enter Valid Email...').css('color','red');
```

Comment: Well you can just achieve this with pure `CSS` too as mentioned in Mr.White and samuelmr's answers.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#email').focusin(function()
{
    $('#email_feed').html('<span style="color:red;">Enter Valid Email...</span>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use css

```
#email_feed
{ 
    color: #F00;
}
```

Or you could continue using jquery and use

```
$('#email_feed').text('Enter Valid Email...').css({ color : "#F00" )};
```

Both will achieve the same result